# Cannot find /howto directory

Tags: command-line

I'm learning how to use the command line in Ubuntu.
In the man intro(1), I have read that I may find more comprehensive information here: usr/share/doc/howto/en

However, the /howto directory does not exist in /doc

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "... learning how to use the command line in Ubuntu ..."

you might be better off with the Bash guides at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html

Otherwise, to locate local files and folders, try e.g.

`locate howto | less`

Which will list a load of stuff,
with the output piped to `less` for paging (press h for help on that)

also 
`man locate` and `man less` may be of help about that.

Answer (score 2):

Hunter,

What they mean by that is that other installed programs will save their "how-to" documentation in the /usr/share/doc/ directory. For instance, if you want more information on the built-in firewall known as "iptables", you would go to /usr/share/doc/iptables/. Unfortunately, not all programs come with a man page or how-to pages.